# REST API to export Archived IM of Skype for Business

Tags: rest, office365api, skype-for-business

I'm searching for a REST api to export the archived IM and Conference of Skype for Business (Online). I can only find powershell command as follows:
[Export-CsArchivingData](https://technet.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/dn951378.aspx)

But this one is for Skype for Business Server 2015 and not sure if this can also be used for SFB Online.

And according to some SFB documents, archived IM and Conference can also be searhed on Office365 Security Compliance screen via Search Content menu. If it can be searched on Office 365, is there any Office 365 API can I use to search the archived IM and Conference?

Thanks in advance.

[About the archiving in SFB Online](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/mt843946.aspx#Anchor_5)

Answer (score 0):

You can search into the conversation history folder of Outlook. You can use this general api to get the last conversations:

```
https://outlook.office365.com/api/v2.0/me/mailfolders/conversationHistory/messages
```

or if you want to search for a specific Text, you can use the following api:

```
https://outlook.office365.com/api/v2.0/me/mailfolders/conversationHistory/messages?$search=%22MySearchText%22
```

Comment: Thank you. But this is for individual IM, I'm looking for api to get the archived IM for all users. And conversation history is different from the archived IM as I have read from Skype for Business document.